# Is it possible to set the path for all frontend AJAX request

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

My slugs looks like this:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '<lang>/<p_page>/<p_category>/<p_product>' => 'splitter/manage-request',
                '<lang>/<p_page>/<p_category>' => 'splitter/manage-request',
                '<lang>/<p_page>' => 'splitter/manage-request',
                '<lang>/' => 'splitter/manage-request',
                '<lang>' => 'splitter/manage-request',
                '' => 'splitter/manage-request',
            ],
        ],
```

I am sending all the requests to that `SplitterController` where I am parsing them. But I don't want the AJAXs to be send to it. Is it possible to give them some default route? To redirect them backend for example. I couldn't find information about it in the documentation? Appreciating links also is I missed it. Thank you!

Comment: not clear, the ajax requests will go on the url you create or assign them. if you dont want your urls to be parsed using the above rules you can add another urlManager component with the name `urlManagerAjax` and the default rules you want, and create the urls for the ajax requests using `Yii::$app->urlManagerAjax->createUrl(['controller/action'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my experience, there are probably the following options for your reference:

the first: The easiest way is to add a beforeAction() to your SplitterController, determine if it is an ajax request in beforeAction(), and redirect to your target address, for example:

```
public function beforeAction() 
{
    if (\Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        return \Yii::$app->response->redirect($targetUrl);
    }
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

second: You can check if the request is an ajax request in the nginx configuration and then redirect to your target address

third: If you can't set up additional routing rules and configure the ajax request address, then you can consider implementing it by customizing UrlManager::parseRequest(), just check if it is an ajax request before it starts parsing the request, then redirect to your target. address

This answer is translated from Google Translate

Comment: Thank you! Already did that. But your answer will be helpful for the others for sure :)